# print canvas in vue-component in electron

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, electron

I creating a SPA with vue.js and the electron-framework. In a vue-component I want to print some labels, which are getting the data from database in mounted state of vue liefecycle. The component is only used for viewing the data in label format and it's a child component. The labels are rendered by canvas-elements.
At first I tried to use the js-function `window.print()` in the mounted function of vue, but the site looks empty. The canvas element won't be printed, even if I convert it to jpg or png and append it with DOM. But it is possible, that I can print some simple text. 
Now I hanging on to print via electron-functions with `webcontens.print()`. I have to call it in the vue-life-cycle, but I dont find a way to communicate
 with electron.
I thinking, I have to steer the current BrowserWindow instance.

Answer (score 1):

## You can communicate with electron using the 'ipc' system provided in the electron package:

In your vue component, import the 'ipcRenderer' like so:

`import {ipcRenderer} from 'electron';`

Then store the canvas data as a base64 string in order to send it via the 'ipc' system:

```
// store the base64 string in a variable
const payload = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
//where 'canvas' is selected via 'document.getElementByID()' or any DOM method
```

Send the 'payload' over to the electron side of the application:

`ipcRenderer.send('canvas:data', payload); //'canvas:data' is just an event name, it could be anything`

Now on the electron side of the application, set up an event listener on 'canvas:data' event to receive the payload:

So on your electron side (typically 'index.js'), import the 'ipcMain' like so:

`import {ipcMain} from 'electron';`

and setup the listener:

```
ipcMain.on('canvas:data', (event, payload)=>{
  console.log(payload); //whatever you want to do here
})
```